# Is there a word to describe a feeling of devotion or love to or being a fanatic to a country that is not my own?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word

*Patriotism* is the word that describes a love or devotion to a person's own country. I'm looking for a similar word except one that describes this same feeling when it is *not* your own country you’re feeling this towards but rather another country that is not your own.

Comment: Orwell (as always) had some [insightful views](http://orwell.ru/library/essays/nationalism/english/e_nat) on this.

Answer (score 17):

Generally, when one has excessive fondness for a country or culture that is not one's own, one would employ a specific term like any of the following:

- *[Anglophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglophile)* - an admirer of Great Britain or England
- *[Americanophile](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile)* - an admirer of the United States of America
- *[Germanophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanophile)* - an admirer of Germany
- *[Francophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francophile)* - an admirer of France
- *[Sinophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinophile)* - an admirer of China
- *[Japanophile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanophile)* - an admirer of Japan
- *[Swedophile](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Swedophile)* - an admirer of Sweden
- *[Philhellene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philhellenism)* - an admirer of Greece

There are many more words formed on analogy with these.

Comment: *philhellenism* - [admiration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/admiration) for Greece and the Greeks and Greek customs

Comment: Great! No doubt there are many, many more.

Comment: My point is that the 'word' is *admiration* ;)

Comment: The reason I don't like this is that it doesn't distinguish between patriotism and being an outside admirer of the country. One can be a patriotic Brit and still be an Anglophile, for instance.

Comment: @AleksandrH I suppose it's technically true but I have a hard time imagining someone using it this way.

Comment: @Casey Yeah I know, most would just use patriotism. Just wanted to point it out anyway :)

Comment: @AleksandrH I tend to think there's a bit of *othering* going on with the -philias; I would never think to call a pair of mated penguins or a ram and his harem *zoophiles* and for similar reason I would assume that someone described with one of these terms was from anywhere but the country in question. (I'd better add that I do not in any way equate these terms with *zoophile*; I just think there's a faint echo of a shadow of connotation shared along with the suffix.)

Answer (score 13):

***[Xenophilous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/xenophilous):***

> - attracted to that which is foreign, especially to foreign peoples, manners, or cultures.

(AHD)

Comment: 'Xenophilic' is the more common, by far, adjective formz

Comment: To me, if someone is a xenophile, that suggests they love or admire anything that is or seems foreign -- "no matter what culture it's from, as long as it's not my own" being the gist. But it doesn't convey admiration for a specific country, which the OP might have been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you asked for single word, that there does not appear to be a single-word solution, and that you used the tag "is-it-a-word", I'll venture a neologism: *ceterapatriotism*.

From your question:

> Patriotism: love of a person's own country

From English-Latin dictionary and knowledge of Latin declensions:

> Patria (f): country
>
> Amor: love
>
> Patriotism/love of a person's own country: amor patriae
>
> Other (f): cetera
>
> Another country: cetera patria
>
> Love of another country, other than one's own: amor ceterae patriae
>
> amor ceterae patriae --> **ceterapatriotism**

If you hate it, you hate it, but it at least answers the question.

Comment: or exopatriotism, or xenopatriotism?

Comment: I'd make it _allopatriotism_ or maybe _heteropatriotism_.

Comment: @AntonSherwood and Octopus: I assumed that *patriotism* was of Latin origin and sought a Latin adjective for "other". I have since found that *patriotism* is of Greek origin. Given that *allo*, *hetero*, *exo*, and *xeno* are also of Greek origin, they are prefix candidates worth considering. They are also in use today and sound better with *patriotism* than my concoction. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: yes, _–iot_ (as in _Cypriot_) and _–ism_ are Greek.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Thanks for your comments. Do any of these alternatives work? If so, which one works best?

Answer (score 0):

## [*allegiance*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegiance)

Two of its meanings may apply, depending on what it is you have in mind.

> 1 a :  the obligation of a feudal vassal to his liege lord
>
> b (1) :  the fidelity owed by a subject or citizen to a sovereign or government (2) :  **the obligation of an alien to the government under which the alien resides**
>
> 2 :  **devotion or loyalty to a person, group, or cause**

Interestingly (I think; **and possibly evidence counter to my suggestion**),

> Although [the French Foreign Legion] is part of the French Military, it is the only unit of the military that does not swear allegiance to France, but to the Foreign Legion itself.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Foreign_Legion